# voice_client and url suddenly not working in discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I've been coding a discord music bot and my simple version worked without any errors! Now I wanted to add the queue function and I designed it so replit.com can handle it. But now I've got errors saying:

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 69, in _play
    vc = ctx.voice_client
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'voice_client'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'voice_client'
```

and in general none of the discord play variables like "is_paused" or "is_playing" work anymore (get the same AttributeError.)!

Here is my code:

```
queue_urls = []

class Music(commands.Cog):
  async def check_for_play(self, ctx):
    if len(queue_urls) > 0: #if there still are more items in the queue...
      await ctx.invoke(self.real_play) #...run the player again

  async def real_play(self, ctx): #the player plays the song...
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    url = queue_urls[0]
    queue_urls.pop(0)
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdlopts) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      URL_NEXT = info['formats'][0]['url']
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL_NEXT, **ffmpegopts), after=lambda e: ctx.invoke(self.check_for_play)) #...and when the song is finished, should run the function check_for_play

  @bot.command(name='play', aliases=['sing', 'p'])
  async def _play(self, ctx): #the command...
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    if not vc.is_connected:
      channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
      await channel.connect()
    url = ctx.message.content
    url = ttourl(url)
    queue_urls.append(url) #...adds the item to the queue...
    voicec = ctx.voice_client
    if not voicec.is_playing: #...and starts the player if its not already playing
      await ctx.invoke(self.real_play)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this error because your cog is incomplete and partly wrong:

- You didn't declared the `__init__` constructor, which is mandatory if you want to access your `bot` variable inside your cog:

```py
class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
```

- You need to replace every `bot` reference to `self.bot`, like so:

```py
voice = discord.utils.get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
```

- Inside a cog, you need to replace `@bot.command()` to `@commands.command()`:

```py
@commands.command(name='play', aliases=['sing', 'p'])
async def _play(self, ctx):
```

Comment: But what is the prefix then? When I type "!play ...", then the command is not found. When I type "play ...", nothing happens?? I don't exactly know what to do here...

Comment: Your prefix is the one you set while declaring your bot (`bot = commands.Bot(...)`). You should look at how [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cogs) are made.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell that you’ve designed a cog here, but the command decorator that you have is incorrect for running a cog. The decorator changes from `client.command()` to `commands.command()`. When you said that this worked in your simplified version, I’m assuming that you had meant a one-file program.

Comment: I literally have no idea what you mean. I've declared "bot" with a prefix and the only thing I've changed is moving the voice.play into another async function.

Comment: Alright, so I had initially thought that you had only taken part of your code and sent it, but it’s apparent now that you don’t know how to make a cog (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html).

Comment: Don't worry, I've now got it. But apparently the bot doesn't run the real_play function... Did I type the wrong syntax for that or what (no error messages)?

Comment: Well, the `ctx.invoke` is meant more for invoking commands into your script, whereas the `real_player` function is not a command. I would recommend having those functions that do not need decorators above your cog class. You can call them with something like `await real_play(self.client, ctx)`.